# Grails run query postgresql on second database to generate Raw JSON

Tags: json, database, postgresql, grails

I have one postgreSQL database which I am using inside my Grails application(configured in Datasource.groovy), lets call it DB1. Now I have other postgreSQL database which has lots of data inside it, lets call it DB2.

I am writing an data export procedure which takes in JSON data generated from DB2, make its domain objects and store it inside the DB1. This data is being sent from another software using DB2. The main problem is that both databases have different column names so it cannot be a direct import export.

PostgreSQL provides direct methods to generate JSON via SQL queries. Eg-

```
SELECT row_to_json(t) 
FROM ( select id, descrizione as description from tableXYZ ) t
```

It returns a JSON output-

```
{"id":6013,"description":"TestABC"}
```

This JSON can be consumed by the code that I have made.

So I want to run this query on DB2 from inside grails application which has DB1 configured inside `Datasource.groovy`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

In your DataSource.groovy file, you need to create another data source to point at DB2.  You can probably clone your dataSource definition for this, eg.

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.9/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources

```
dataSource_db2 {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    username = "XXX"
    password = "YYY"
    //noinspection GrReassignedInClosureLocalVar
    dialect = PostgreSQLDialect
    autoreconnect = true
    useUnicode = true
    characterEncoding = "utf-8"
    tcpKeepAlive = true

    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    properties {
        // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
        initialSize = 5
        maxActive = 50
        minIdle = 5
        maxIdle = 25
        maxWait = 10000
        maxAge = 10 * 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1000 * 60 * 1 // 1 min
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1000 * 60 * 5 // 5 min
        numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
        validationQuery = 'SELECT 1'
        validationQueryTimeout = 3
        validationInterval = 15000
        testOnBorrow = true
        testWhileIdle = false
        testOnReturn = false
        defaultTransactionIsolation = Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
        removeAbandoned = true
        removeAbandonedTimeout = 20 // 20s is a long query
        logAbandoned = true // causes stacktrace recording overhead, use only for debugging
        // use JMX console to change this setting at runtime

        // the next options are jdbc-pool specific
        // http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes
        // https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html
        jmxEnabled = true
        // ResetAbandonedTimer resets the timer upon every operation on the connection or a statement.
        // ConnectionState caches the auto commit, read only and catalog settings to avoid round trips to the DB.
        jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;ResetAbandonedTimer;SlowQueryReportJmx(threshold=10000)"
        abandonWhenPercentageFull = 25 // settings are active only when pool is full
    }
}
```

To use it for database connection access, you can inject the javax.sql.DataSource into your Services, Controllers, Domain classes, or other Grails Artefakts.

eg.

```
import javax.sql.DataSource
import groovy.sql.GroovyResultSet
import groovy.sql.Sql

MyService {
   DataSource dataSource_db2

   def doQuery(String query) {
      new Sql(dataSource_db2).rows(query)
   }
}
```

To have a domain object use your db2 dataSource for GORM, add to your domain objects 'mapping' block:

```
   static mapping = {
      datasource 'db2'
   }
```

If you want JNDI support, you can also add something like this in your resources.groovy:

```
xmlns jee: "http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
jee.'jndi-lookup'(id: "dataSource", 'jndi-name': "java:comp/env/jdbc/db1")
jee.'jndi-lookup'(id: "dataSource_db2", 'jndi-name': "java:comp/env/jdbc/db2")
```

Comment: If you'll be doing batch processing, you should read this about doing batch operations in Hibernate (v3):  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html